# Drag & Drop Files and Items in Unity !

Tags: unity, multimedia, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and drop files (media files specifically) in my Unity. While playing videos or music, if I like to drop another file in the totem/vlc media player, how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag-and-drop works brilliantly in Unity (in 11.04). You can drag and drop both directly onto open windows, or onto the applications launcher.

In the screenshot below I'm drag-n-dropping a video file. The launcher fades the icons of all the programs that can't handle a video file, leaving only Banshee and Totem. Note that in this example then Totem is already open, but Banshee isn't. Both light up to allow you to drag-and-drop into them.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It looks really neat but maybe its happening with me because; (a) it is only in 11.04, or.. (b) I am using Ubuntu Netbook Remix ! So let me see if I can do it after an upgrade :)

Comment: You'd be correct, this is a new feature of 11.04.

Comment: upgraded to 11.04 and it worked :D

Comment: but is there no way that when you hover with the dragged file on the launcher, then the main window is restored so you could drop it in a particular location on the window? e.g. a split pane file manager. Dropping onto the launcher is ambiguous in that case.