# Drag and drop file to existing VLC player

Tags: nautilus, vlc, drag-and-drop

Whenever I try to drag and drop a file to an existing VLC player ( as per [Drag & Drop Files and Items in Unity !](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32192/drag-drop-files-and-items-in-unity) ), it seems to open a new VLC window and start playing from there. Is it possible to run it from the existing open window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open vlc > tools > preferences. there is an Instances section, enable "Allow only one instance'

There is also an option to " Enqueue files when in one instance mode" On recent versions of vlc that actually works. Enable if desired & see if it does.

Make sur you click save on your way out of prefs

Comment: doug, you're a life saver. Will vote up your answer as soon as I have enough rep points :)